# Flex 4.6 Need to know how to animate a .swf in actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, animation, flash

I've converted a PowerPoint into Flash so each slide is a .swf.  I've used a number of different converters and the problem here is the same.

What I'd like to do is trigger the .swf's animation (contents of slide appearing) programatically.  I can click on the .swf with a mouse and the animation advances.  I can automate this when the .swf's embedded in a web page simply by doing:

document.getElementById('myMovie').play();

Each time I execute that code, the swf advances to the next animation.  However, I can't find a way to do this in flex.  I've used then MovieClipSWFLoader and tried:

```
private function animate():void {
var simulatedClick1:MouseEvent = new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK);
var simulatedClick2:MouseEvent = new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN);
var simulatedClick3:MouseEvent = new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP);
frameNo++;
myMovie.gotoAndStop(frameNo);
myMovie.nextFrame();
myMovie.nextScene();
myMovie.play();
myMovie.dispatchEvent(simulatedClick1); // with clicks 1, 2, and 3
}

<s:MovieClipSWFLoader id="myMovie" source=""/>
<s:Button id="btnAnimate" click="animate()"/>
```

I've also tried loading as an Image component and using the simulated click too... no good.  Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the .swf was created with Flash 8 and wasn't compatible with my version of Flex.  I found a great solution in ForcibleLoader at https://gist.github.com/nsdevaraj/409902.  It converts old .swf's to new ones and then the code worked as it should.

```
private var libMC:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

ur = new URLRequest(guide_url);
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, swfComplete);
var fLoader:ForcibleLoader = new ForcibleLoader(loader);
fLoader.load(ur);
swfMovie.addChild(loader);

private function swfComplete(event:Event):void{
libMC = event.currentTarget.content as MovieClip;
}           

private function animate():void {
libMC.nextFrame();

<mx:UIComponent id="swfMovie"/>
```